# Strategy for visualising rotations about an axis

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have an exam on abstract algebra specifically to do with colouring of various shapes.
The problem is I really struggle with visualising the various rotations.

Lets say I have a cube and it has an axis going through the central of 2 opposite edges around which the cube is rotated by $\pi$

How can I strategically work out what happens to the various edges and vertices under this rotations?
Any tips to help visualise this?

Comment: I think it's mostly case by case, and visualising big-ish graphs is fairly hard: I have no problems keeping track of a cube's vertices in my mind, but I wouldn't dare with a dodecahedron... For the example you mention: the edges bisected by the rotation's axis touch two faces. The rotation simply swaps and flips those two faces, and this accounts for all the $8$ vertices.

Comment: By the way: I always prefer to visualise rotations with the axis vertical (in the case of your example, with the cube "standing" on an edge).

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to post an image as an answer, but on your test you can presumably make sketches. (There's certainly no need for a stereogram, as below, but if you cross your eyes to "fuse" the two cubes, it should "pop" into 3-D.)

The rotation in your question exchanges vertices with unprimed and primed labels.

[image: Stereogram of a cube rotated through a half turn]